# custom validation rule is not triggered

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using the `areSame` rule from [here](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/User-Contributed-Rules):

```
ko.validation.rules['areSame'] = {
    getValue: function (o) {
        return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
    },
    validator: function (val, otherField) {
        return val === this.getValue(otherField);
    },
    message: 'The fields must have the same value'
};
```

And apply it like this:

```
this.confirm = ko.observable().extend({
    areSame: {
       params:this.password
    }
});
```

But it's never even triggered. I put debugger into `validator` function of the rule definition:
        validator: function (val, otherField) {
            debugger
            return val === this.getValue(otherField);
        },
however the flow never visits this point. What could be wrong?

**EDIT:**

The problem of not triggering validation is solved by calling `ko.validation.registerExtenders();`, however the rule doesn't work as expected. The problem is that the `otherField` variable, that is passed to `validator`, is the object
`{params:*observable here*}`, where as the method `getValue` doesn't expect that as you can see from the source code. So either the source code is wrong or I defined the params for the rule in the wrong way. So which one?

Comment: Have you called `ko.validation.registerExtenders()` to register your custom rule?

Comment: Nope, I didn't do that since I didn't know I needed to :). Please post it as an answer as once I did that it the validation was triggered

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Although it is not explicitly stated in the [Wiki](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules) (it is in the sample code but not in the description) but

**you need to call `ko.validation.registerExtenders()`**

after you have defined your custom rules in order to register them:

```
ko.validation.rules['areSame'] = {
    getValue: function (o) {
        return (typeof o === 'function' ? o() : o);
    },
    validator: function (val, otherField) {
        return val === this.getValue(otherField);
    },
    message: 'The fields must have the same value'
};

ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

In order to use your custom rule you don't need the "params syntax" so you can just write:

```
this.confirm = ko.observable().extend({
    areSame: this.password
});
```

If you want to use the "params syntax" you need to provide a custom error `message` property, otherwise the plugin does not correctly interprets the `otherField` argument :

```
this.confirm = ko.observable().extend({
    areSame: {
       params: this.password,
       message: 'a custom error message'
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Marked as the answer. It's off-topic, but any change you could tell me how to use localization with custom rules?

Comment: Good question, I've never used the localization feature of the plugin and so I don't know. But writing something like `ko.validation.localize({ areSame: 'Your localized error message.'});` should work in theory. Of course you need to add this after your `ko.validation.rules['areSame']`.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I'll try it. Please also see my updated question - the validation is now triggered, however it doesn't work as expected